# Visual Basic - Getting list of URLs from SourceCode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, text-parsing

I have been working on a program that will enable me to monitor which of my companies clients are linking to our website. If I can get it working it would save a lot of time being wasted searching through clients websites manually.

Currently I have a database that stores all clients HomePage URLs. My program is looping through these URLs, grabbing their SourceCode and placing the SourceCode into a textbox. It then searches through the textbox for my companies URL and either returns a 'True' or 'False' value.

If 'True' then the link is present but if 'False' I need my program to search the other pages on the same site and check to see if the link is present anywhere else.

**To do this I need my program to cycle through the SourceCode(in textbox already) and find all other URLs that link to other pages on the same site (e.g www.example.com, www.example.com/contact-us, www.example.com/about) and store them in a list. Im not sure how to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an solution based on...

[Regex Help: Get list of URL(s) except extention .css, .js, .jpg, .gif, .png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598146/regex-help-get-list-of-urls-except-extention-css-js-jpg-gif-png)

```
            Dim MyRegex As New Regex("href=""(?<URL>(?:(?!javascript)(?!#))[a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$" + "\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]+)" + "(?<!(?:\.png|\.js|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.css|\.gif|\.zip|\.r" + "ar))""(?:$|>|\s)", RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

            Dim matches As MatchCollection = MyRegex.Matches(textbox1.text)
            For Each item In matches
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString())

            Next
```

You'd then need to filter out the non-relevant sites?

Comment: Thanks mate exactly what I was after!